# Express/EJS app not connecting to custom css

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I have just started an Express app and am having trouble getting connected to my custom css file.

This is the top of my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path    = require("path");

const app     = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static("public"));
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I've tried all three of the express.static options and I am pretty sure they all work because when I put an index.html in the public folder it renders that fine.
This leads me to believe that my issue is with how I am linking in my header.ejs
The SemanticUI link is working no problem so I am sure my header.ejs is being rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" />
    <link rel="sytlesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

This is my file structure:

```
|node_modules
|public
  |stylesheets
    -main.css
|views
  |paritals
    -footer.ejs
    -header.ejs
    -nav.ejs
  -landing.ejs
  -header.ejs   
  -move.ejs
-app.js
-package-lock.json
-package.json
```

I'm sure I must be missing something really basic but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Can you access css file in your browser?

Comment: I can link to the main.css from the index.html if I put it in the public folder but not from my header.ejs.

Comment: The git bash console which I am using to start the server shows nothing.  In the chrome console I got `semantic.min.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at semantic.min.js:11`.  I tried putting in a CDN to jQuery but it didn't help.

Comment: In reference to the access from the browser.  I'm not sure what I responded with is what you meant.  Did you mean access it from the browser address window?  I put  /public/stylesheets/main.css in there and just got a 404 but would that would show anything even if I was linking to it?